# The navigator.product property can be used to detect bots?

Tags: javascript, http, bots, navigator

The "navigator.product" JavaScript property of "navigator" object can be used to detect a bot?

From what I know the majority of bots in the web are simple requests that take the content of a page without render it, this variable communicates the rendering engine in use by the client, and this bots does not have one.

It could be used to detect a bot?

Comment: My guess, without any evidence to back it up, is that most bots are either not going to execute JavaScript at all, or are going to be running enough of a browser-like environment to populate things like navigator.product.

Comment: This is better done server-side, since a bot can change its useragent, or can decide to not run your Javascript.